# Iterate through XML element[n] childs

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to iterate through a list and can't manage to do it.

```
  public void SetShipmentsIndex(int shipmentId, string sourceShipmentIndex, IEnumerable<XElement> shipments)
  {
        var currentShipment = shipments.ToList()[shipmentId];

        foreach (var el in currentShipment)
        {
            if (el.Name == "sourceShipmentId")
            {
                el.SetValue(sourceShipmentIndex);
            }

            if (el.Name == "shipmentIndex")
            {
                el.SetValue(shipmentId);
            }
        }
    }
```

above produce an error:
`foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' because 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

`shipments` contains 3 elements.

i am trying to get to `shipments[shipmentId]` and loop though his descendants.
How can i accomplish that?

Comment: i need to loop through `var currentShipment = shipments.ToList()[shipmentId];`  it's gives me an error

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Which element is going to be equivalnet to shipmentId ? or if you are using xml element as index then change  var el in currentShipment into  var el in currentShipment.Elements()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the childs of the element like this:

```
foreach (var el in currentShipment.Elements())
    {
        if (el.Name == "sourceShipmentId")
        {
            el.SetValue(sourceShipmentIndex);
        }

        if (el.Name == "shipmentIndex")
        {
            el.SetValue(shipmentId);
        }
    }
```